# objects of which types can always be allocated at page boundary?

Tags: c, linux

On Linux, I am interested to know if at page boundary, some object type can always be allocated.  For which C types, is this always guaranteed? Please point me to standard/documentation  from which the answer follows.

Clarifying code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char TYPE;

int main()
{
    TYPE val;
    void *mem;
    mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(val), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy(mem, &val, sizeof(val));

    /* is *(TYPE*)mem guaranteed to be the same as val ? */
}
```

The answer for `char` is yes, guaranteed.

For which other types is the answer yes, guaranteed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250038/discussion-on-question-by-mark-galeck-objects-of-which-types-can-always-be-alloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object alignment requirements are determined by the hardware architecture (processor being used), because it is the processor that may not be able to load data from unaligned addresses.  (In some cases, the kernel can provide unaligned address support by trapping the processor interrupt generated by an access attempt via an unaligned address, and emulate the instruction.  This is slow, however.)

The hardware architectures supported by the Linux kernel are listed at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch.html.

We can summarize these by saying that there is no hardware architecture supported by Linux that requires more than 128 bytes of alignment for any native data type supported by the processor, and page sizes are a multiple of 512 bytes (for historical reasons), so we can categorically say that on Linux, all data primitives can be accessed at page-aligned addresses.

(In Linux, you can use [sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) to obtain the page size.  Note that if huge pages are supported, they are larger, a multiple of this value.)

The above covers all C data types defined by the GNU C standard library and its extensions, because they only define scalar types, structures with elements aligned at natural boundaries (not *packed*), and vectorized types (using GCC/Clang vector extensions designed for SIMD architectures).

(You can define a *packed* structure that has to be allocated at a non-aligned address if you are really evil, using GCC [type](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) or [variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html).)

If we look at the C standard, the type `max_align_t` (provided in `<stddef.h>` by the compiler; it is available even in freestanding environments where the standard C library is not available) has the maximum alignment needed for any object (except for evilly constructed *packed* structures mentioned above).

This means that `_Alignof (max_align_t)` tells you the maximum alignment required for the types the C standard defines. (Do remember to tell your C compiler the code uses features provided by the C11 standard or later, e.g. `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu2x`.)

However, certain architectures with SIMD (single instruction, multiple data –– for which GCC and other C compilers have added [vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), for example implementing the Intel `<immintrin.h>` MMX/SSE/AVX etc. intrinsics), may require larger alignment for vector registers, up to the size of the vector registers.  (This is where that 512 bits comes from.)  On x86-64 (64-bit Intel and AMD architectures currently used) there are separate instructions for unaligned and aligned accesses, with unaligned accesses possibly slower than aligned accesses, depending on the exact processor.  So, `_Alignof(max_align_t)` does not apply to these vectorized types, using vector extensions to the C standard.  The C standard itself refers to such types as "requiring *extended* alignment".

In Linux, all types passed to the kernel, including pointers, must retain their information when cast to `long`, because the Linux kernel syscall interface passes syscall arguments as an array of up to six `long`s.  See [include/asm-generic/syscall.h:syscall_get_arguments()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/syscall.h) in the Linux kernel.  (While this function is implemented for each hardware architecture separately, every implementation has the same signature, ie. passes the syscall arguments as `long`.)

The C standard does not define any relationship between the pointer address, and the value of a pointer when converted to a sufficiently large integer type.  This is because there historically were architectures where this relationship was complicated (for example, on 8086 'far' pointers were 32-bit, where the actual address was `16*high16bits + low16bits`).  In Linux, however, the relationship is expected to be 1:1.  This can be seen in things like [/proc pseudo-filesystem](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), where pointers (say, in `/proc/self/maps`) are displayed in hexadecimal.  See [lib/vsprintf.c:pointer_string()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c), which is used to convert pointers to strings for userspace ABIs: it casts the pointer to `unsigned long int`, and prints the number value.

This means that when pointer `ptr` is `N`-byte aligned, in Linux, `(unsigned long)ptr % N == 0`.

While the C standard leaves signed integer overflow for each implementation to define, the Linux kernel [expects and uses](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/programming-language.html) the [GCC behaviour](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html): signed integers use two's complement, and wrap around analogously to unsigned integers.  This means that casts between `long` and `unsigned long` do not affect the storage representation and lose no information; the types only differ in whether the value they represent is considered signed or unsigned.  Thus, any of the logic above wrt. `long` equally applies to `unsigned long`, and vice versa.

Finally, you can variants paraphrasing the statement *"on all currently supported architectures, ints are assumed to be 32 bits, longs the size of a pointer and long long 64 bits"* in both the kernel sources and on the Linux Kernel Mailing List, LKML. See e.g. [Christoph Hellwig in 2003](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=106183991314389). The patch (to documentation on adding syscalls) to explicitly mention that Linux currently only supports ILP32 and LP64 models [was submitted in April 2021](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=161800098920071) with positive reactions, but hasn't been applied yet.

Comment: I am sorry, thank you for the detailed exposition, but...  I know all this...  it does not help, because...  you are saying, the return of `mmap()` is divisible by 128.  No - the return of `mmap()` is a pointer and pointers do not have division operation.  Pointers can only be subtracted, if they belong to the same allocated array, and integer can be added to a pointer. And the representation of pointer as bit integer, is implementation dependent, so also we cannot infer anything about divisibility by 128.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: You tagged the question [tag:linux], and in Linux, pointers are compatible with the `unsigned long` type, because Linux only supports ILP32 and LP64 architectures using the SysV ABI.  In other words, in Linux, you **always** use `unsigned long address = (unsigned long)pointer;` to obtain the unsigned integer address that pointer points to. It is on this value you do the arithmetic on, then convert it back to a pointer via `pointer = (void *)address`.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: The above means that when you use `sometype *ptr = mmap(...);` and `(void *)ptr != MAP_FAILED`, i.e. the mapping was successful, `(((unsigned long)ptr) % 512 == 0)` is guaranteed in linux, and `ptr` sufficiently aligned for any and all primitive and composite (non-packed) types.  Indeed, you can even find constructions like `othertype *aligned_ptr = (void *)(((unsigned long)ptr | 15) + 1)` to get an address aligned to 16 byte boundary, when "ptr" has at least 16+15=31 bytes of extra space for `othertype` available.  Do you need me to add to my answer listing these with references?

Comment: thank you, can you point me to some kind of official reference/documentation about this unsigned long vs pointer equivalence.  It would help me greatly if I can read about it.  I just grepped the SysV ABI and I could not find anything about pointers.  There are also supplements on specific architectures, that is no good, because my programs must be portable, not just for x86 and AMD architectures.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: In the Linux kernel, system call ABI is defined as passing `long args[6]` (see e.g. [include/asm-generic/syscall.h:syscall_get_arguments()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/syscall.h#L117) in the Linux kernel sources).  This means that any userspace pointer passed to the Linux kernel must be both valid as-is, and contain all information about the pointer value when cast to `long`.  While the function is implemented differently for each architeture, they all pass the syscall parameters as `long`. [...]

Comment: @MarkGaleck: [...] As to `long` vs. `unsigned long`, Linux specifies [GNU C 11](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/programming-language.html), and GCC applies [modulo arithmetic on both signed and unsigned types, and binary and two's complement signed integer types only](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html), so there isn't any real difference between `long` and `unsigned long`.

Comment: Finally, you can variants paraphrasing the statement *"on all currently supported architectures, ints are assumed to be 32 bits, longs the size of a pointer and long long 64 bits"* in both the kernel sources and on LKML.  See e.g. [Christoph Hellwig in 2003](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=106183991314389).  The patch (to documentation on adding syscalls) to explicitly mention that Linux currently only supports ILP32 and LP64 models [was submitted](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=161800098920071) in April 2021 with positive reactions, but hasn't been applied yet.

Comment: thank you, I was aware of the points in your original answer, but I was not aware of any of the stuff in your comments.  If you could gather your comments into the answer and add to your original answer (perhaps shorten the original points), I will accept it, I think it will be useful for any future readers.

Comment: I am going to disagree with you on one point though.  IMO, the discussion of `_Alignof` is wholly irrelevant.  C11 standard specifically says that `_Alignof` has to do with the difference of pointers, _not_ with any divisibility of one pointer. Please comment.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: The reason for the odd wording in the C standard is that the numerical value of pointers is implementation defined.  In Linux (and basically all currently used architectures, but not in some old architectures no longer used – 8086, for example, used 32-bit addresses for 'far' pointers, where middle 4 bits were duplicated), the numerical value directly maps to the address.  So, in Linux, an `N`-aligned pointer `ptr` fulfills `((uintptr_t)ptr) % N == 0`.  For any properly aligned object `obj`, `((uintptr_t)(&obj) % _Alignof(obj)) == 0`.  I'll edit the post later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Now updated.  Let me know if I forgot any of the salient points that you believe are relevant and useful to others as well.

Comment: thank you.  After this discussion with you, I decided that the level of portable and official support is not enough for me to rely on, even though I have no doubt in your answers, but my situation is special because I have to have an "official" documentation, such as C standard to fall back on.  It's fine, I can do with reading types from any address by byte accumulation.